# Check Service worker installation progress from component (angular)

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have updated my angular app into PWA, since I need to preload all of the assets on the first launch (application have a lots of images, which are used for UI).
That's why I would like to show some kind of spinner/loading bar during service worker install event and hide it when it's done. 
So first question - is it possible to handle this event from the component?

I have found this example and tried to add it inside first component, that loads on app launch,  but didn't get any logs. So probably it doesn't work that way.

```
ngOnInit() {
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    this.log("INSTALLING ");
    const installCompleted = Promise.resolve()
                        .then(() => this.log("INSTALLED"));

    event.waitUntil(installCompleted);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    this.log("ACTIVATING");
    const activationCompleted = Promise.resolve()
        .then((activationCompleted) => this.log("ACTIVATED"));
        event.waitUntil(activationCompleted);
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    this.log("HTTP call intercepted - " + event.request.url);
        return event.respondWith(fetch(event.request.url));
    });
}

log(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

Also I have a question about caching assets. In my ngsw-config.json I'm using next setup:

```
  "name": "assets",
  "installMode": "prefetch",
  "updateMode": "prefetch",
  "resources": {
    "files": [
      "/assets/**"
    ]
  }
```

but when I'm opening first page, in cache it doesn't show all the images and folder from /assets. Not event half of them. Is it ok and it's not supposed to show all the images that are cached? Is it possible that the problem is because I'm using lazy loading modules and service worker start caching when each module is loaded?
On other hand, when I'm switching pages, in Network tab it shows that each image is loaded from service worker...
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can enhance your Angular service worker behaviour using the technique described here (link broken):

http://jakubcodes.pl/2018/06/13/enhancing-angular-ngsw/

It basically registers an intermediate script file as the service worker JavaScript file and in this, the Angular script besides own code is called.

**Edit**

The process in detail:

1. Create two js files in your src folder (e.g. "sw-master.js" and "sw-custom.js"). The latter may contain your custom service worker code.
2. Add these two lines to your "sw-master.js" (import the custom script before the NGSW script):

   ```
   importScripts('./sw-custom.js');
   importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');
   ```
3. Register the two new assets in the "angular.json" file of your project:

   ```
   "assets": [
     "src/favicon.ico",
     "src/assets",
     "src/manifest.json",
     "src/sw-master.js",
     "src/sw-custom.js"
   ],
   ```
4. Register the master script instead of "ngsw-worker.js" in your "app.module.ts":

   ```
   ServiceWorkerModule.register('/sw-master.js', { enabled: environment.production })
   ```

Comment: Link only answers are not beneficial to the site. If the site you linked goes down then this answer would no longer be relevant. The link should supplement the answer provided, not be the answer altogether.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Thanks @MrCircuit, good idea, but in my case "install" and "activate" events are called, but not "fetch" event. Am I supposed to intercept all GET request from NGSW when it try to cache all assets ?

Comment: I found a possible solution : reverse the order of script imports in sw-master.js file. so my custom code registers event handler in the first place. Don't know if it's a safe solution, it gives me the impression that only one fetch event is allowed.
And fetch event does not seem to intercept all requests, i got only some assets requests but not all of those cached