# Enhancing angular ngsw service worker

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm trying to intercept all requests from NGSW service worker to check if all my files are cached (and display a message to user to say that app is ready).

I based my work on that post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56067366/1381820

Process in details :

1. Create two js files in the src folder (e.g. "sw-master.js" and "sw-custom.js").
2. "sw-master.js" contains :

```
importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');
importScripts('./sw-custom.js');
```

3. Register the two new assets in the "angular.json" file of the project:

```
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
  "src/manifest.json",
  "src/sw-master.js",
  "src/sw-custom.js"
],
```

4. Register the master script instead of "ngsw-worker.js" in the "app.module.ts":

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('/sw-master.js');
```

My sw-custom.js looks like that :

```
console.log('Hello from sw-custom.js');

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log("[SW] HTTP call intercepted - " + event.request.url);
    return event.respondWith(fetch(event.request.url));
});
```

**First main point** : fetch event only seems usable once.
To get logs, it's necessary to reverse the order of script imports in sw-master.js file.

**My problem** : Console logs does not return all assets when http server logs return all :

Logs return by fetch event (sample showing only one svg) :

[image]

Logs returned by http server (sample, showing lot of svgs) :

[image]

Is there a good way to enhance NGSW fetch event ? and how can i be sure that all asssets are fetch in my sw-custom ?

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

The only suspicious thing that I found is that `ServiceWorkerModule.register` seems to allow specifying different registration strategies - the default one being `registerWhenStable:30000'`. I also noted that there is `registerImmediately` strategy.

Comment: As i remember, i didn't found any solution when i encountered this problem 4 years ago. But i'm still interested by any new ideas ;)

Comment: I am also exploring this functionality and I am no expert by any meaning. 

The only two things that I found related to this are either the `scope` (perhaps the sw is not scoped to watch for requests in the assets endpoint) and the `registration strategy` (registration of the sw happens sometime after those resources are required).